# Did I choose the wrong database for the job? DynamoDB vs Aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-aurora, dynamodb-queries

I'm building a real estate website with property listings, some filters to search and an address field with autocomplete. It's working fine, but the **performance on the autocomplete is super slow**. It takes almost a second to get a response. Considering all services are in my region I think that's pretty slow.

I improvised sort of a "fuzzy" search where I split the source string (for example if the user searches for "Jumeirah, Rimal" becomes ["jumeirah", "rimal"]) and try to match a location's full "path" (a string like locationID/city/community/sub-community/tower, in this example "are.1.50/Dubai/Jumeirah Beach Residence/Rimal") to each part of the split string. The expression becomes something like this:

```
contains(#path, :fullString) OR 
(contains(#path, :stringOne) AND contains(#path, :stringTwo) AND ... )
```

The important thing is that because I need to use the "contains" operator, I can't do it efficiently with a KeyExpression and I need to use the slower FilterExpression with a full scan. I only have 7,500 locations to search from and the performance is pretty bad already.

This made me think if I should use an SQL based database like Aurora. AFAIK SQL can execute complicated queries very efficiently.

I will also look into AWS's elastic search solution.

What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DynamoDB is most performant when you are able to perform a query operation to find an exact partition key, using the scan operator will likely lead to a performance hit and lead to increased usage of read credits.

Whilst a relational database such as Aurora can perform this operation, using ElasticSearch will likely be more performant for this operation.

By using ElasticSearch functionality for performing a [fuzzy search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) is supported and is one of the key benefits to using this as a document store.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the AWS equivalent of this service? There is ElasticCache and Elasticsearch.

Comment: This would be the ElasticSearch service :)

Comment: And it is relatively common for people to use DynamoDB -> KDS -> ElasticSearch all together to get the best of these worlds.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Postgresql Aurora, use this: https://hub.packtpub.com/how-to-perform-full-text-search-fts-in-postgresql/

That's Full-text search inside the DB with indexes (check GIN and RUM index types). no need to duplicate your data out of the DB into a Elasticsearch instance also you can get more creative from there and use extra fields from your db to rank the results in a better way. absolutely recommended. e.g. now that I know these rows match the fuzzy search, let's do an inner join get extra data and tweak the ranking function to show geolocated results by distance (PostGIS)

I saw some guys saving more than 80% of their bill by removing the elasticsearch server and serving that FTS query from its own postgres